# Adding results from ckdTree cluster to DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scipy-spatial

I'm trying to use ckdTree to find all of the data points within a specified distance (1500 m). I have a dataframe of centres, and a dataframe of raw data. My plan was to use the x and y coordinates extracted from the clusters to build a new dataframe of the data points that meet specific criteria. Here's what I have:

```css
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial as spatial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = perfed[['X', 'Y']].values
centres = producers[['X', 'Y']].values

x_list = []
y_list = []

point_tree = spatial.cKDTree(points)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(centres)))
for center, group, color  in zip(centres, point_tree.query_ball_point(centres, 1500), colors):
    cluster = point_tree.data[group]
    x, y = cluster[:, 0], cluster[:, 1]
    x_list.append(pd.Series(x))
    y_list.append(pd.Series(y))
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=color, s=10)

d = {'X': [x_list],
     'Y': [y_list]}

output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index').transpose()


# output = output.merge(producers, how='left', left_on='X', right_on='X')

plt.show()
```

The input dataset is just UTM x and y coordinates. Can anyone spot where I'm making the mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker found this solution. It could be likely done in less lines, but it works.

```html
count = 0
merge_x_list = []
cluster_x_list = []
for a in x_list:
    for b in a:
        merge_x_list.append(b)
        cluster_x_list.append(count)
        
    count+=1
    
count = 0
merge_y_list = []
cluster_y_list = []
for a in y_list:
    for b in a:
        merge_y_list.append(b)
        cluster_y_list.append(count)
        
    count+=1
    
output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y', 'cluster'])
    
output['X'] = pd.Series(merge_x_list).values
output['Y'] = pd.Series(merge_y_list).values
output['cluster'] = pd.Series(cluster_x_list).values
```